# Boiling Vegetables minimum number of cuts

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem
https://warmup.kattis.com/problems/vegetables

What i am wondering is how should one divide a vegetable into two pieces.
If I make wleft=wright=1/2 * w then it is not possible to get the same output as sample.

In hint/tips/Insight they have written 
Insight: All cut pieces of one vegetable are of the same weight.

But this doesn't make any sense to me.
1000 1400 
will give me
1400 -> 700 700 
1000
no ratio is 700/1000 so we must divide 1000
1400 -> 700 700 
1000 ->500 500
Now I don't know how i should divide because i can only do 3 split in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boils down to a breadth-first search over the number of cuts combined with the different possible cuts. First, you check the solution using zero cuts, then all solution using one cut etc, until you find one where all are sufficiently equal in size.

Note:

- There's no point cutting the smallest veggie when considering the next cut, as it will only make the ratio worse.
- Any solution for all vegetables is also a solution for any two of them. You can use this to prune the search in order to avoid searching for the best cut in hopeless cases.
- If you imagine a graph, you have a root vertex where every vegetable is whole. Every edge then cuts one vegetable, leading to a new vertex. At first, this looks like a tree, but it is just a DAG. The order in which you cut two veggies doesn't matter, after you cut both, the paths will converge at a single vertex again. Make sure you don't try this same vertex twice, as it will blow up the number of possible cuts you have to handle.

Combining the three notes above, the only edge worth considering is the one that cuts the largest vegetable in a bigger number of pieces. Using this knowledge, you should be able to efficiently implement this algorithm.

Comment: Will a cut split a vegetable in two equal size pieces? In insight they wrote something like this

Comment: Looks promising, but I think you need to say that each vertex represents a number of cuts applied to each vegetable (e.g. in an array), and each edge in this graph *adds one cut to the number of cuts applied so far to a particular vegetable*.  E.g. at some vertex where vegetable #42, weighing 60g, has already been chopped into 5 12g pieces, adding 1 more cut will cut it into 6 10g pieces.

Comment: @user3105383: The point is that it's always better to cut the vegetable into equal-sized pieces than any other way.  Why?  You're trying to cut the vegetable into k pieces that are all either bigger than some minimum size, or smaller than some maximum size.  If you're in the former case and you have to make some piece bigger to meet the minimum size, then some other piece will neccessarily be even smaller, so that's no use; and if you're in the latter case and you have to make some piece smaller to meet the maximum size, then some other piece will necessarily be even larger, so that's no use.

Comment: Yes, @j_random_hacker, that description of a vertex is accurate. For vegetables A, B, C, the root node is {A/1, B/1, C/1}, and I'm assuming that it's sorted by veggie size. The next node from there will be {A/1, B/1, C/2}, or maybe {A/1, C/2, B/1} after sorting.

Comment: "the only edge worth considering is the one that cuts the largest vegetable in a bigger number of pieces" -- this is right, and I realise that it actually means that the DAG explored by the BFS tree becomes just a single path!  :)  It's correct because if you don't cut that vege *now*, you'll still need to cut it *later* or you won't decrease the min:max size ratio (which we know is still too small because if it wasn't we would have already terminated), so you might as well always cut it now.

Comment: ... provided that by "the largest vegetable" you meant "the vegetable whose pieces are the largest, given the number of cuts it currently has".

Comment: Funny. When I wrote that answer, I didn't realize this implication. I saw that it was not a tree but a DAG because paths could converge, but not that it was just a single one.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt I am having difficulty understanding "Any solution for all vegetables is also a solution for any two of them. You can use this to prune the search in order to avoid searching for the best cut in hopeless cases." What does prune the search means?
How can any sol for 2 veg also be a sol for 3 or 4 veg.?

Comment: "You're trying to cut the vegetable into k pieces that are all bigger than some minimum size" " you have to make some piece bigger to meet the minimum size, then some other piece will neccessarily be even smaller,"
thoes pieces that are smaller will they be larger than the min size? This min size is it a specific size for one vegetable?

Comment: It's not that a solution for two is one for three, but one that is not a solution for two is also not a solution for three. Now, "pruning" is a technique when you are searching in a large tree. Basically, if you know from a partial solution that this will never lead to a complete solution, there's no need pursuing this any further.

Comment: Thanks I think i get it now but I have one question.
No that we have one path to consider do we have to back track?
i mean let say i cut the largest into 3 part but the correct sol would cut it into 5 parts. Should my algo just try all the different cut one the largest and then continue with the second vegetable to cut. There will be many cases ex: cut larget into 3 pieces cut sort and cut the largets into 2 pieces or cut it into 3 pieces, 4 pieces etc. test all the options that are valid.
How would someone program the more general case that u described in ur answer. With a DFS tree.

Comment: Backtracking only applies when you descend deep into a graph and then retrace your steps to take a different way at an earlier point.

Comment: In this case do I need to backtrack? or should i explore all the possible combinations. With combinations i mean cut first veg in 2 piece second in 2 or 3 or 4 etc.
and then try again and cut the first veg into 3 pieces . This corresponds to backtrack in a graph right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not sume that all the vegetables should be divided into 2 pieces.

it only tells you that you should have the "smaller average size" with the minimum number of cuts.

So, If a piece of vegetable (i.e. Brocolly) weights 2 grams, and a piece of potatato weights 6 grams, then, if you use no cuts, the average is 4, and the ratio is 3 to 1.

but I you use 3 cuts in the potato, then you get 4 pieces of 2 grams, and ratio 1...

hope it helps.

Comment: Ratio is largest/smallest but do we need to know the average?   Problem is to decide how to make a single cut. If we take the first example.  2000 3000 4000 how should one divide 4000? Should the weight of each new part after one cut be of equal size?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem using python3 can be found at [my Github](https://github.com/joelagrell/cuttingVegetables).

If you wanna try by yourself first i would focus on creating a solution where you only cut the biggest piece and keep track of the original weight so you can "recut" the vegetable in new parts while iterating solutions.

Comment: I believe it should be ok to give a general overview of the algorithm instead of spoon feeding line by line code.
Afterall this is a algorithm question and Joel's answer is an algorithm.